# How to call Twitter gem methods on the twitter api client in the view file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, global-variables

I have spent hours looking through stackoverflow and can not find a simple explanation on how to call the twitter gem's methods in the view file. I have a very simple rails set up, with the following files and have set the twitter api client to be a global variable in order to test this. It works in the rails console, but I can not get it working in rails. The error I get is `undefined method "followers" for nil:NilClass`

config/initializer/twitter.rb

```
require 'twitter'

$client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = 'xxxx'
  config.consumer_secret = 'xxxx'
  config.access_token = 'xxxx'
  config.access_token_secret = 'xxxx'
end
```

welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

index.html.erb (for welcome.rb)

```
<h1>Hi there</h1>

<p><%= $client.user %></p>
```

It should just return my user details, as I have hard typed all my auth keys direct into the config file (I will abstract these later once I get this working).

Many thanks

Comment: Was my answer any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should be asking yourself is why you want the actual twitter client methods in the view it seems like its a poor architectural decision on the surface. It is hard to image a that there is not a better way to organize you app so that that this is not required.

To answer you question though what could work is creating a client object as an instance variable and passing it to the view and have a helper that incapsulates the twitter client methods and call them in the view; see below.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  require 'twitter'

  def index
    @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = 'xxxx'
      config.consumer_secret = 'xxxx'
      config.access_token = 'xxxx'
      config.access_token_secret = 'xxxx'
    end
  end
end

#app/helper/welcome.rb
module WelcomeHelper
  def welcome_tweet(twitter_client, message)
    twitter_client.send_tweet(message)
  end
end
```

I think that a better solution though is to just send the results of the twitter client methods into the view as an instance variable(s) and display them there. Over coupling your view to and external systems methods is a code smell and a bad idea